# pass plaid link tokens to the client side in react

Tags: reactjs, plaid

would anybody happen to know how to pass plaid link tokens to the client side in REACT? I already tried using the code from plaid quickstart but it is in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used it, but Plaid publishes an [SDK for React](https://github.com/plaid/react-plaid-link) that has some [examples](https://github.com/plaid/react-plaid-link/tree/master/examples), that would probably be a good place to start!